# Produce data from one table, with a unique field from another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull data from a table called "Alphadata" whilst pulling some data from one called "TLAuth" - Now, the data that comes from Alphadata will not always have a direct comparison in TLAuth as it's a table that is updated manually by other staff via a form in a specific circumstance.

Current code is:

```
SELECT Alphadata.Invoice, Alphadata.DateRaised, Alphadata.Amount, Alphadata.Staff, TlAuth.Invoice, TLAuth.TlAuthID 
FROM (Alphadata LEFT JOIN TlAuth ON Alphadata.invoice = TlAuth.invoice) LEFT JOIN Agents ON Alphadata.Staff = Agents.Alphaname
WHERE (((Alphadata.DateRaised) Between [Start Date:] And [End Date:]));
```

When this runs it pulls everything I want, HOWEVER it duplicates the TL Auth fields and as such gives me an incorrect total for each member of staff and as a whole.

I'm thinking it's a "Group By" function, but I'm not 100% on how to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, try adding DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Alphadata.Invoice, 
    Alphadata.DateRaised, 
    Alphadata.Amount, 
    Alphadata.Staff, 
    TlAuth.Invoice, 
    TLAuth.TlAuthID 
FROM 
    (Alphadata 
    LEFT JOIN 
        TlAuth 
        ON Alphadata.invoice = TlAuth.invoice) 
        LEFT JOIN Agents 
        ON Alphadata.Staff = Agents.Alphaname
WHERE 
    Alphadata.DateRaised Between [Start Date:] And [End Date:];
```

Comment: That worked for now. I think I've got a problem with how the dates are recorded somewhere. Is there a chance you know how to get the TL.Invoice to link ONLY when the field (from the same table labelled "DateAuthorised" and the Alphadata.DateRaised are the same?

Comment: Then you must add an _inner join_ between the fields `DateRaised`.